# Is there a word that means "someone that was betrayed"

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

There's a word for someone that betrays, eg. the traitor and I wondered, is there a specific, single english word that means, "someone that was a victim of a betrayal"? So something that isn't broad and can be used for a variety of scenarios such as victim.

Comment: Not sure if there's a single word. Look into "betrayal trauma". It's a term often associated with victims of betrayal.

Comment: You should say *someone **who*** not *someone that*.

Comment: Betrayed works just fine. "The betrayed often find it difficult to trust again."

Comment: The betrayer betrayed the betrayee?

Answer (score 1):

Someone who has been betrayed can simply be referred to as "***the betrayed***".

This is similar to how you would say "*the deceased*", as in -

- Half the services I've been to, the presiding reverend never met *the deceased* and still managed to say something nice.

Therefore, "*the betrayed*" works just fine. Taking David M's example from the comments -

> *"**The betrayed** often find it difficult to trust again."*